# I want to use CDI with Java SE 12, but start up failes (Main Class, JBoss or Payara, all the same error)

Tags: servlets, dependency-injection, cdi, weld, java-ee-8

I got completely stuck. I want to use CDI2 with Servlets to write a simple web app. However, the beans not get loaded.

I get the following error in JBoss or Payara or Weld (if running as Main Application):

```
WELD-001524: Unable to load proxy class for bean Managed Bean [class MyBean] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

Does anyone still use CDI2 or has a running modern example?

I compile with maven.

warm regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself. I had the wrong dependencies. I got confused because of Jakarta. I used the CDI-2 maven dependency. So I updated to Jakarta. Right? This is the way to go, right?

I can deploy. Payara-Micro works. JBoss (WildFly should do the same)
However, Payara Micro does not get track of the URL patterns of simple Servlets, although still, one can call it over the client. (Intellij has a CDI tab, gives a nice overview itself)

...

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: If you run in a java/jakarta-ee server, the weld dependency should not be there or (if you need it for unittests) have a provided or test scope

Comment: Yes, thanks reminding. Makes sense, as weld is built in the app server.

Comment: So please improve your answer.